# Third cohomology of mapping class group

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, group-cohomology, mapping-class-groups

I would like to know the *third* cohomology with *coefficients in* $U(1)$ or $\mathbb{C}^\ast$ of the mapping class group of a surface of genus at least one. I found many results on the rational cohomology (in particular of the stable MCG), but no results on the integral cohomology (or even cohomology with the above coefficients) in degree three.

Comment: For a genus 1 surface that's just the cohomology of $GL_2 \mathbb Z$ which I think is fairly classical.  For higher genus I would look at papers of Mustafa Korkmaz.  I don't recall the current state of the art but I believe his work would be a good reference-point.

Comment: As Ryan said, $g=1$ is classical (but I don't know it off the top of my head). For $g=2$ see "Mapping class groups of low genus and their cohomology" by Benson and Cohen, they determine in fact all the torsion in $H^\ast(\Gamma_2)$. It seems you don't care about rational cohomology but let me mention that most likely $H^3(\Gamma_g,\mathbf Q)$ always vanishes. When $g=3, 4$ this is due to Looijenga (resp. Tommasi) and when $g \geq 6$ this follows from Harer stability/Madsen-Weiss theorem, so only $g=5$ could fail.