# What are the low-degree group cohomology of the mapping class group of a surface

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, group-cohomology

Let $MCG_g$ be the mapping class group of genus $g$ closed surface.
(Say $MCG_1=SL(2,Z)$).
I would like to know what is the group cohomology of $MCG_g$ with coefficients in Z, such as $H^2(MCG_g,Z)$and $H^3(MCG_g,Z)$.

http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9503230 contains a result $\bar H^n(SL(2,Z),Z)=Z_{12}$ for $n=$even, and $\bar H^n(SL(2,Z),Z)=0$ for $n=$odd. But I do not know what
$\bar H^n$ means (Torsion?)

Also, I like to know what is $H^2(SL(n,Z),Z)$. Thanks!

Comment: In general, the cohomology groups of mapping class groups are very much not known. Much more is known about stable mapping class groups, i.e. if you consider the mapping class groups of surfaces of genus $g$ with one boundary curve for $g$ large (see, e.g. http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0401168v1.pdf).

Comment: And I guess, $\bar H^n(SL(2,Z),Z)$ refers to the reduced cohomology, i.e. we leave out the $\mathbb{Z}$ in degree $0$. By the way, there are several further sources for "unstable" homology of mapping class groups: http://msp.org/gtm/2008/14/gtm-2008-14-001s.pdf and http://hss.ulb.uni-bonn.de/2011/2610/2610.pdf from the Bödigheimer school come to my mind, which were written after Korkmaz' survey.

Comment: @Lennart Meier: Thanks. The newer refs are for mapping class group with a boundary. I wonder do you know new refs for the case without boundary.

Comment: I'm guessing that you are interested only in certain low-degree cohomology groups for MCGs. If that is indeed the case, I suggest that you modify your question: you'll get substantially more informative answers if you say explicitly which degrees you care about.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/162383/third-cohomology-of-mapping-class-group?rq=1

Comment: You should have a look at Harer's papers

Comment: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=INDI&s1=81320&vfpref=html&r=30&mx-pid=700769 and http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=INDI&s1=81320&vfpref=html&r=22&mx-pid=1106936

Answer (score 2):

See  [M. Korkmaz' paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0307111) For the mapping class group. For the $SL(n, \mathbb{Z})$ see [this question.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64551/cohomology-of-lattice-subgroups)